# When a recipe calls for X cooked amount of something is that before or after it has been cooked?

Tags: measurements

I think I know the answer to this and realize that it is similar to this [question about nuts](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4572/809), but I wanted to verify my instinct. When a recipe calls for 1 ½ cups cooked X, is that recipe calling for that ingredient measured before or after cooking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When a recipe calls for a cup of chopped nuts, should they be measured before chopping or after chopping?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/when-a-recipe-calls-for-a-cup-of-chopped-nuts-should-they-be-measured-before-ch)

Comment: @Mien if you ***read*** my question you'll see that I referenced the [question about nuts](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4572/809). I'm kind of an interloper here, so if you want to close the question by all means do so, but I felt like this provided a significant enough difference (cooked vs uncooked) to warrant the question.

Comment: I know you linked to that question, but in my opinion (and when seeing a lack of close votes, I guess I'm alone in this), the reasoning/answer/explanation is totally the same.

Comment: @Mien I see where you are coming from, including that in your original comment would have been helpful. Alone the comment looks like I didn't read your question, but did you see this one. :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But the comment was made automatically. And you asked your question because you didn't know for sure the same reasoning applied. I can live with it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recipe-speak is very particular about order.

- *half a cup of butter, melted* means you measure the solid butter (probably with a butter ruler) and then melt it
- *half a cup of melted butter* means you melt some larger amount of butter and then measure (probably with a liquid measure)

Obviously there's no difference between *3 carrots, roasted* and *3 roasted carrots*. Nor between *2 eggs, hardboiled and sliced* and *2 hardboiled sliced eggs*. And in many cases the volume of things isn't much affected by cooking. In some cases it is easier to measure before or afterwards, and the recipe-writer wants to point you in the easier way. But in some it really matters. Rice, for example. 1 cup of raw rice yields roughly 3 cups cooked, so recipe writers need to be super clear which you are measuring.

In your example, 1.5 cups cooked X, you cook it and then measure it.